# 1-to-cn Relationship in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this requirements:

- a System can have a Module (exactly 1) or noone
- if we have a Module, he must be part of a System.

How can I do that in SQL Server Management Studio?

I thought about setting the Primary key of the Module-Table as the same primary key in the System-Table, which is idSystem.

Is it right? How can I do that exactly?

Comment: what is `cn` in a `1-to-cn` relationship? many?

Comment: it is [1,1] to [0,1]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of accomplishing this.  The first and my preferred for this scenario is the one you described.  Then add a foreign key constraint on Module.SystemID referencing System.ID, this will guarantee you don't have orphaned records.

```
System
- ID PK IDENTITY

Module
- SystemID PK with FK_Module_System
```

The second scenario is valuable if a module needs to be referenced by multiple systems.  Then add a foreign key to System.ModuleID referencing Module.ID.

```
System
- ID PK IDENTITY
- ModuleID with FK_System_Module

Module
- ID PK IDENTITY
```

And finally for completeness, a many to many relationship would require a lookup table.  Here you would want two foreign keys.

```
System
- ID PK IDENTITY

SystemModule
- ID PK IDENTITY
- SystemID with FK_SystemModule_System
- ModuleID with FK_SystemModule_Module

Module
- ID PK IDENTITY
```

Comment: thanks! but how can i do that in sql? I would do the 1st scenario aswell..  do you have an sql statement? the System-table is already done and is working since a while with primary key "idSystem"

Comment: I'd recommend just using Sql Management Studio to create any tables and relationships.  Right click on 'Tables', click 'Add', click 'Table' and the designer will open.  Then right-click in whitespace and 'Add Relationships' to get the designer for that.  Also, idSystem is non-standard and will limit your ability to use frameworks that can make your life easier.

Comment: like hibernate/maven? because i had the modules embedded in the systems table, and i want to extract them now in a special table for modules

Comment: can anyone still help?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.  You just need to create the table and relationships as I described.  From there if you're using EF/hibernate/maven you'll have to create your new model(s) and add mappings.  You should be able to reference what is done with the system table.

Comment: you said "idSystem is non-standard will limit my ability to use frameworks that can make my life easier..." I thought you're talking about the 1st solution and I am asking which frameworks? do you mean hibernate or maven?